# How do you handle a key sequence inside a function?

Tags: key-bindings, hydra

I want to run a function and do different actions based on the next key sequence.

I have this.

```lisp
(defun ask-for-C-b-or-M-b (key-sequence)
   (interactive "KPress Key")
   (cond
    ((seq-set-equal-p key-sequence
                      [?\C-b]) "C-b pressed")
    ((seq-set-equal-p key-sequence
                      [?\M-b]) "M-b pressed")))

 (call-interactively 'ask-for-C-b-or-M-b)
```

This works for `C-b` but not for `M-b` and I would like to use the kbd function

```
(kbd "C-b") instead of [?\C-b]
(kbd "M-b") instead of [?\M-b]
```

I'm trying to get extra keys in a [hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) without making a new hydra

```lisp
(defhydra hydra-test
   nil
   "test hydra"
   ("SPC" ask-for-C-b-or-M-b "Do complicated thing"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the missing link you're looking for is `listify-key-sequence`, which will "convert a key sequence to a list of events". Luckily, this works for both key sequences and for the values returned by `kbd`, so the following should return true:

```lisp
(equal (listify-key-sequence [?\C-b])
       (listify-key-sequence (kbd "C-b")))
```

So your function would be:

```lisp
(defun ask-for-C-b-or-M-b (key-sequence)
   (interactive "KPress Key")
   (cond
    ((seq-set-equal-p (listify-key-sequence key-sequence)
                      (listify-key-sequence (kbd "C-b")))
     "C-b pressed")
    ((seq-set-equal-p (listify-key-sequence key-sequence)
                      (listify-key-sequence (kbd "M-b")))
     "M-b pressed")))
```